# how can I store a newly appended element into a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get a reference to a node directly after it is appended?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162677/how-can-i-get-a-reference-to-a-node-directly-after-it-is-appended)

as an example:

```
$(document).append('<div class="new-elem" />');
```

how do i now store the above newly created element into a variable so i can use it like this:

```
newElem.append('div class="another-new-element" />');
```

where newElem is the element i appended to the document initially?

i'm assuming it can't be done like:

```
var newElem = $(document).append('<div class="new-elem" />');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do the opposite with [`appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/):

```
var newElem = $('<div class="new-elem" />').appendTo(document);
```

Comment: feel a bit stupid for not seeing it...

Answer (score 1):

you should use [`appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/):

```
var newElem = $('<div class="new-elem"></div>').appendTo(document);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're looking to have a variable reference to what you appended first, you might as well just do this:

```
var el = $('<div class="blah">');
$(document).append(el);
el.append('<span>test</span>');
```

Comment: and I suppose appendTo will also work haha